# User fields empty in parse-server server.js mail adapter

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I use [parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter](https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter) and would like to know how to localize the verification email and reset password email.

My clue is to check user's fields and then assign the correct template on `server.js` or `AmazonSESAdapter.js`. The problem is that user properties are empty, besides email, username.

For instance, at the example below, `firstName` is undefined.

Thanks.

```
emailAdapter: {
      module: 'parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter',
      options: {
        // The address that your emails come from
        fromAddress: 'Iron rr',
        accessKeyId: 'gg',
        secretAccessKey: 'gg',
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        // The template section
        templates: {
          passwordResetEmail: {
            subject: 'Redefinir sua senha Iron Trainers',
            pathPlainText: '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/test/email-templates/password_reset_email.txt',
            pathHtml: '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/test/email-templates/password_reset_email.html',
            callback: (user) => {
                return {
                  firstName: user.get('firstName')
                }
              }
              // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
          },
          verificationEmail: {
            subject: 'Confirmar email no Iron Trainers',
            pathPlainText: '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/test/email-templates/verification_email.txt',
            pathHtml: '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/test/email-templates/resendEmailVerification.html',
            callback: (user) => {
                return {
                  firstName: user.get('firstName')
                }
              }
              // Now you can use {{firstName}} in your templates
          },
          customEmailAlert: {
            subject: 'Urgent notification!',
            pathPlainText: '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/test/email-templates/custom_alert.txt',
            pathHtml: '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/test/email-templates/custom_alert.html',
          }
        }
```

Comment: By localize you mean `en`, `eu` language type localization or something else?

Comment: yes, language translation. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the `server.js` too?

Comment: this above code is from server.js, I can also post the complete file/code.

Comment: Yeah do a pastebin of the same, remove any confidential info.

Comment: here you go: https://pastebin.com/SChhZVw4 , thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169923/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-jorge).

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify the callback is getting called? I can provide a solution in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding this can be done but through a code change in the plugin.

There is a `if-else` condition at below line in code

https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter/blob/0bce9b6c81681c3829a17b208d839d23c846ab05/src/AmazonSESAdapter.js#L90

Since you have not provided any feedback and I have not way to setup this, I have assume that the else part is what gets executed

```
  const {
    link,
    appName,
    user,
    templateConfig
  } = options;
  const {
    callback
  } = templateConfig;
  let userVars;

  if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
    userVars = callback(user);
    // If custom user variables are not packaged in an object, ignore it
    const validUserVars = userVars && userVars.constructor && userVars.constructor.name === 'Object';
    userVars = validUserVars ? userVars : {};
  }

  pathPlainText = templateConfig.pathPlainText;
  pathHtml = templateConfig.pathHtml;

  templateVars = Object.assign({
    link,
    appName,
    username: user.get('username'),
    email: user.get('email')
  }, userVars);

  message = {
    from: this.fromAddress,
    to: user.get('email'),
    subject: templateConfig.subject
  };
}
```

Now in this part, 2 lines decide the template to be used

```
pathPlainText = templateConfig.pathPlainText;
pathHtml = templateConfig.pathHtml;
```

By this time, the `callback` you have provided has been called. Now in the callback you can set a variable, let assume it is name `locale`. So you can update the code like below

```
pathPlainText = templateConfig.pathPlainText + (userVars["locale"] || "en");
pathHtml = templateConfig.pathHtml + (userVars["locale"] || "en");
```

And then you will create templates which have the `locale` in the file path and with updated code the correct template will be picked.

You can also look at `@bgran` answer, at first look I do believe that should work as well

Comment: This will definitely work, but you'll need to fork `parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter` if you want to use it.

The answer below will work with the existing `parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter`.

Comment: Yes, totally agreed and highlighted in my last line as well

Comment: @TarunLalwani, thanks a lot, this works perfectly. Although, I have one more question... how could I access another parse class in the callback, not only the user object? thanks.

Comment: It hard to say because if it in an object in a scope which you can't control it would be tough. Also a class and instance are two different things. If you want to use class you can just required it but if you need an instance then you will need to make code modification and see how they can shared between the two scopes

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do your localization in the template callback.

The callback is synchronous, so all of your localization will also need to be synchronous.

`emailTemplate.html`

```
<div>
  {{localizedText}}
</div>
```

Other templates for each locale:

`emailTemplate.en.html`

```
<p>
  Hi {{nome}}...
</p>
```

The emailer logic:

```
// The same templater used by parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter
import template from 'lodash.template'

/* ... */

const TemplatesByLocale = {
  en: fs.readFileSync('./emailTemplate.en.html'),
}

verificationEmail: {
  /* ... */
  pathHtml: './path/to/emailTemplate.html',
  callback: (user) => {
    const locale = getLocaleSomehow(user) // needs to be synchronous
    const localizedTemplate = TemplatesByLocale[locale]

    const compiled = template(localizedTemplate, {
      // same interpolation as parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter
      interpolate: /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g
    })
    const localizedText = compiled({
      nome: user.get('nome'), /* ... */
    })
    return {
      localizedText: localizedText,
    }
  },
  /* ... */
}
```

It's worth noting that `parse-server-amazon-ses-email-adapter` will use the HTML template (the one specified via `pathHtml`) before it uses the plain text template, so if you've specified an HTML template you can just leave off the `pathPlainText` property.

Comment: This won't work because there is decision making that needs to happen based on the variables and that cannot be done in the template

Comment: You can do the decision making in the template callback.

Guess this wasn't clear in the answer, but you do the localization in the template callback and then render the result in the template.

Comment: Can you add a example of the same to your answer?

Comment: Sure thing, will add an example.

Comment: If you need to have separate template files for each locale, the example above will work.

This is kind of a hack around the library though, and you'll need to write only synchronous code in the template callback.

Comment: From the code supplied, it's not clear whether they need to localize the entire template or just a few fields.

If it's just fields, the original method would work.

Comment: I believe it has to be the template, also the OP hasn't responded much from last few days. So just use assumptions as you like :-)